# Download Zip file attached on gmail

Tags: gmail, 3.0-honeycomb, motorola-xoom, zip

I recieved an email with a zip file. But I'm not able to download even having some installed apps that can open zip files.

Is there any way to enable the zip file download?

I'm trying to do this on a Motorola Xoom 3.0

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/how-do-i-download-pdf-documents-from-gmail

Comment: It doesn't work on xoom =(

Comment: There seems to be a way to patch your Email apk to allow this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=26270768&postcount=18 . I guess it would also work with Gmail. Once I've been able to try this, and if it works, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gmail app doesn't support downloading attachments. It does support viewing a limited amount of mimetypes.

If you want to download the zip file, you'll need to go to gmail.com using the browser on the phone and download it from there.

Another alternative is to use another android email client. K-9 Mail works well with Gmail accounts and can both download attachment to the SD card as well as open them from the mail itself.

Comment: Or use an alternate email client like K9 to allow you to do so. If you frequently view/download attachments on your device, it might be worthwhile to look @ K9.

Comment: sorry for the duplicate ... was typing and didn't see the comment

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll use the web client everytime I want to download something.